# Difference between e-residence permit and common format residence permit for the purpose of transit through the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, transit

I am Russian citizen and I am going from Italy to Bridgetown (Barbados) with a transit in London.

I will arrive at 23:05 in London (LHR) terminal 1 with Alitalia Airlines and will go to final destination the next day 11:30 from London (LHR) terminal 3 with Virgin Atlantic.

Would I need a transit visa for this itinerary?

For the transit visa I have:

- You arrive and depart by air.
  OK
- You have a confirmed onward flight that leaves on the day you arrive or before midnight on the day after you arrive.
  OK
- You have the correct documents for your destination (eg a visa for that country).
  OK
- You have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country **I DON'T KNOW** because I have a residence permit in Italy, but I am not sure if it is a e-residence permits (that is not acceptable for transiting through immigration control without a visa).

In italian my residence permit is called "Permesso di Soggiorno Elettronico". Please help me find the difference between e-residence permit and others.

Comment: Is it a plastic card with a bull on it?

Comment: Yes it is plastic card

Comment: Does it have a bull?

Comment: Yes, It is a plastic card with a bull and 5 stars

Comment: Your question seems to be based on the assumption that an e-permit is not the same as a common format permit, but that appears to be incorrect.  Where did you get that information?

Comment: HERE https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/russia/transit/somewhere_else/yes I found information that to travel without visa I must also "have a common format residence permit issued by an European Economic Area (EEA) country" BUT "E-visas or e-residence permits are not acceptable for transiting through immigration control without a visa"

Thats why I have a question: Which one residence permit I have?

Comment: I am pretty sure that by "e-visa" and "e-residence-permit" they mean visas and permits that are processed online and stored in a database, and for which the traveler has no more than a self-printed confirmation as evidence.  However, I did not find official confirmation of this.  The EU common format residence permit is *required* by the current version of the regulation to have an electronic chip, so interpreting the terms otherwise does not make sense.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is the new [electronic residence permit (PSE)](https://questure.poliziadistato.it/it/Cosenza/articolo/11405943b53a6cc14509518829), introduced in 2015, which is more secure than the previous one and more difficult to counterfeit. It complies with [EC Regulation no. 1030/2002, as amended by the EC Regulation n. 380/2008](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/en/TXT/?uri=CELEX:32008R0380) and is *common format residence permit issued by an EEA Member State or Switzerland*.